# Linux private file encryption

Tags: linux, encryption

I need to store and secure clients files.

I would like to encrypt files and not being able to open it.
Only file owner can open his file. I think I’ll have to generate private key for each customer. How can I encrypt and store files without being able to open it myself.

Problem n°2: I’d like client to be able to share his files with other client account (and delete share)

Comment: You should use asymmetric crypto and encrypt the files using client's public keys, and only the clients will hold the corresponding private keys to decrypt the files.

Comment: The customer has to generate the public,private key pair, and he should do the encryption before the file arrives at your space.

Comment: File must be not crypted, and crypted once stored. File will always stay online. When client open the file, I want to decrypt it and send to client.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution for problem 1

when encrypting with gnupg do not use your ID in the list of recipients. This will allow only recipients to be able to decrypt

## Solution for problem 2

When one client (A) wants to share with another client (B): both keys already present in system. Use client A&B keys to re-encrypt the file. Now they both have access to the same file.

Comment: File sent are video files from webcam so client canot crypt before to send the file. I receive the file, store it in client folder, then crypt. Id client wants to view file in player. Decrypt and open it in player.

Comment: updated using your described usecase